# GCC does not recognise libxml2 functions

Tags: c, parsing, gcc, libxml2

When trying to compile a simple parsing program using libxml2, GCC returns this error.

```
/tmp/ccuq3Hc1.o: In function `main':
xmltesting.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `htmlCreatePushParserCtxt'
xmltesting.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `htmlCtxtReadFile'
xmltesting.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>
#include <libxml/HTMLtree.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int main()
{

    htmlDocPtr doc;
    htmlNodePtr org_node;
    htmlNodePtr curnt_node = NULL;

    htmlParserCtxtPtr parser = htmlCreatePushParserCtxt(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

    doc = htmlCtxtReadFile( parser, "html.txt", NULL, 0);
    org_node = xmlDocGetRootElement( parser->myDoc );

    for ( curnt_node = org_node; curnt_node; curnt_node =  curnt_node->next ) {

        if ( curnt_node->type == XML_TEXT_NODE ) {

            printf ("%s", curnt_node->content );

        }

    }

}
```

It seems to be reading the structs fine, but the functions are not to be found?

Or is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably simply have to tack an `-lxml2` at the end of the gcc build line.

---

As Dietricg Epp points out in the comments, if your library has the right `.pc` file `pkg-config` is the preferred way to get the neccesary flags. You can get both compile and link flags.

```
$ pkg-config libxml-2.0 --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/libxml2  -lxml2
```

Comment: Or with pkg-config, you can use `$(pkg-config --libs libxml-2.0)` instead of `-lxml2`.